# 14.04 -- Rock Candy XBox 360 controller not detected

Tags: 14.04, games, steam

I just switched from a lifetime of using Windows to Ubuntu.  Wiped out my entire computer and made a linux-only computer (to force myself to learn).

So far, Ubuntu is a lot of fun and very interesting.  I know nothing.
My only hangup is I am trying to configure everything I need in order to play ZSNES, PSX_1.13, Skyrim (steam), etc., and despite following instructions from every source I could google, my OS (Ubuntu 14.04) does not agree that I have a controller plugged in.

It's doing the flashing light thing that others have mentioned, and I don't mind that.  I know it's connected that way at least.

Xboxdrv says:

"No Xbox or Xbox360 controller found"

...Is there anything I can do beyond this?